# How to find a table with Web::Scraper based on cell values?

Tags: perl

Want process a several html pages with tables.

The pages:

- contains several classless tables, the only way how to identify the correct one
- the needed table has in the 1st cell value "*Content*"

Question: How to find a correct table based on its cell value with Web::Scrape or Scrappy or another tool?

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Web::Scraper;
use YAML;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $table = scraper {

    #the easy way - table with class, or id or any attribute
    #process 'table.xxx > tr', 'rows[]' => scraper {
    #unfortunately, the table hasn't class='xxx', so :(

    process 'NEED_HELP_HERE > tr', 'rows[]' => scraper {
        process 'th', 'header' => 'TEXT';
        process 'td', 'cols[]' => 'TEXT';
    };
};
my $result = $table->scrape( $html );
say Dump($result);

__DATA__
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
<table><tr><th class="inverted">header</th><td>value</td></tr></table>
<!-- here are several another tables (different count) -->

<table> <!-- would be easy with some class="xxx" -->
   <tr>
     <th class="inverted">Content</th> <!-- Need this table - 1st cell == "Content" -->
     <td class="inverted">col-1</td>
     <td class="inverted">col-n</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <td>2012</td>
     <td>2001</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Banana</th>
     <td>val-1</td>
     <td>val-n</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mention there is no class on the table, but in your example you display one.  Also, are you just trying to get the `<th>` row?

Comment: @moshen: some of the `<th>` elements have class attributes but not the `<table>` ones, so there's nothing to distinguish the table of interest from any other. He's trying to get the contents of all the `<th>` and `<td>` elements of that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an XPath expression to look at the text content of the nodes.

This should do the trick

```perl
my $table = scraper {
  process '//table[tr[1]/th[1][normalize-space(text())="Content"]]/tr', 'rows[]' => scraper {
    process 'th', 'header' => 'TEXT';
    process 'td', 'cols[]' => 'TEXT';
  };
};
```

It may look complex, but it's OK if you break it down.

It selects all `<tr>` elements that are children of any `<table>` element beneath the root for which the first `<th>` element of the first `<tr>` element contains a text element equal to `"Content"` when normalized (leading and trailing spaces stripped).

**output**

```
---
rows:
  - cols:
      - col-1
      - col-n
    header: Content
  - cols:
      - 2012
      - 2001
    header: Date
  - cols:
      - val-1
      - val-n
    header: Banana
```

Comment: YES! Exactly what i want. Thank you, very much! Just need understand it somewhat ;)

Answer (score 3):

[HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) seems to be good for this problem.

Give this a try.

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib qw( ..); 
use HTML::TableExtract; 
use LWP::Simple; 

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(Content)] );
my $content = get("http://www.example.com");
 $te->parse($content);

foreach my $ts ($te->tables) {
   print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
   foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
      print join(',', @$row), "\n";
   }
 }
```

If you change this line

```
 my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(Content)] );
```

to

```
 my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
```

It will return all of the tables. So you can fiddle around with that line if the above code block doesn't give you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: `HTML::TableExtract` is indeed beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) wins for compactness. Unlike Scraper, it's not necessary to name the results, but if you want to, it's just one extra line.

```
use Web::Query qw();
Web::Query->new_from_html($html)
->find('th:contains("Content")')
->parent->parent->find('tr')->map(sub {
    my (undef, $tr) = @_;
    +{ $tr->find('th')->text => [$tr->find('td')->text] }
})
```

Expression returns

```
[
    {Content => ['col-1', 'col-n']},
    {Date    => [2012,    2001]},
    {Banana  => ['val-1', 'val-n']}
]
```

Comment: OMG, this is harder to understand than Xpath.. ;) But, thanx for the Web::Query, first time see it.

Comment: No, CSS selectors are easier to understand than XPath selectors.